# FHIR - Extending a operation parameter (Additional parameters in Patient Resource)

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

[image]

https://www.hl7.org/fhir/parameters.html

is it right to add the additional parameters in extended operation or can we add the add the parameters in patient resource type . because if we have multiple values we are not able to map the patient data with the extended operation parameter.

how to add additional parameters in patient resource type???

Comment: are you trying to add additional properties to patient resource ?

Comment: @ELYusubov yes, is there a concept to add additional parameters within the resource object ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Every element in a resource can have extension child elements to represent additional information that is not part of the basic definition of the resource.

Here is the post on HL7 FHIR with detailed info and samples on [Extensibility](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/extensibility.html)

Comment: Parameters should not ever appear inside of a Bundle.  Its intended to be the root payload when invoking an operation.  It is never used to supplement existing data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Every element in a resource or data type includes an optional "extension" child element that may be present , So we can add the additional parameter with an extension

***Eg:*** 
{
  "resourceType" : "Patient",
  "extension" : [{
    "url" : "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-citizenship",
    "**extension**" : [{
      "url" : "code",
      "valueCodeableConcept" : {
          "coding" : [{
             "system" : "urn:iso:std:iso:3166",
             "code" : "DE"
          }]
       }
    }, {
      "url" : "period",
      "valuePeriod" : {
         "start" : "2009-03-14"
      }
    }]
    }]
}